# how to batch insert data into Google BigQuery from a Java service?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I've read through a few similar questions on SO and GCP docs - but did not get a definitive answer...

Is there a way to batch insert data from my Java service into BigQuery directly, without using intermediary files, PubSub, or other Google services?

The key here is the "batch" mode: I do not want to use streaming API as it costs a lot.
I know there are other ways to do batch inserts using Dataflow, Google Cloud Storage, etc. - I am not interested in those, I need to do batch inserts programmatically for my use case.

I was hoping to use the REST batch API but it looks like it is deprecated now: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/batch

Alternatives that are pointed to by the docs are:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll REST request - but it looks like it will be working in the streaming mode inserting one row at a time (and cost a lot)
- a Java client library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/dev-guide

  After following through the links and references I ended up finding this specific API method promising: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/BatchRequest.html

  with the following usage pattern:

```
Create an BatchRequest object from this Google API client instance.

Sample usage:

 client.batch(httpRequestInitializer)
 .queue(...)
 .queue(...)
 .execute();
```

Is this API using the batch mode, not streaming one, and is the right way to go ?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "batch" version of writing data is called a "load job" in the Java client library. The [bigquery.writer](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#writer-com.google.cloud.bigquery.WriteChannelConfiguration-) method creates an object which can be used to write data bytes as a batch load job. Set the [format options](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/WriteChannelConfiguration.Builder.html#setFormatOptions-com.google.cloud.bigquery.FormatOptions-) based on the type of file you'd like to serialize to.

```java
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FormatOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobStatistics.LoadStatistics;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDataWriteChannel;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.WriteChannelConfiguration;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.UUID;

public class LoadLocalFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String datasetName = "MY_DATASET_NAME";
    String tableName = "MY_TABLE_NAME";
    Path csvPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", "my-data.csv");
    loadLocalFile(datasetName, tableName, csvPath, FormatOptions.csv());
  }

  public static void loadLocalFile(
      String datasetName, String tableName, Path csvPath, FormatOptions formatOptions)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
      // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
      // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);

      WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration =
          WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId).setFormatOptions(formatOptions).build();

      // The location and JobName must be specified; other fields can be auto-detected.
      String jobName = "jobId_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      JobId jobId = JobId.newBuilder().setLocation("us").setJob(jobName).build();

      // Imports a local file into a table.
      try (TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(jobId, writeChannelConfiguration);
          OutputStream stream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)) {

        // This example writes CSV data from a local file,
        // but bytes can also be written in batch from memory.
        // In addition to CSV, other formats such as
        // Newline-Delimited JSON (https://jsonlines.org/) are
        // supported.
        Files.copy(csvPath, stream);

      }

      // Get the Job created by the TableDataWriteChannel and wait for it to complete.
      Job job = bigquery.getJob(jobId);
      Job completedJob = job.waitFor();
      if (completedJob == null) {
        System.out.println("Job not executed since it no longer exists.");
        return;
      } else if (completedJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
        System.out.println(
            "BigQuery was unable to load local file to the table due to an error: \n"
                + job.getStatus().getError());
        return;
      }

      // Get output status
      LoadStatistics stats = job.getStatistics();
      System.out.printf("Successfully loaded %d rows. \n", stats.getOutputRows());
    } catch (BigQueryException e) {
      System.out.println("Local file not loaded. \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#loading_data_from_local_files
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-from-file
- [system test which writes JSON from memory](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/49cbb0f16ac3236e2f87b44570994d7235485902/google-cloud-bigquery/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/it/ITBigQueryTest.java#L2747)

Comment: thank you, Tim. Do you happen to have an example for writing from memory? Do you mean something like this: StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); sb.append("field1Value, field2Value, field3Value"); // add many more lines==rows ; stream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());  ?? With FormatOptions.csv() ?  Thank you!!

Comment: @Marina Yes, something like that. FormatOptions.csv() will construct the right thing. https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/FormatOptions.html#csv-- For more complex types, you might need to use JSON or Avro instead. This system tests show writing JSON from a string: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/49cbb0f16ac3236e2f87b44570994d7235485902/google-cloud-bigquery/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/it/ITBigQueryTest.java#L2747